# How can I make a SwiftUI List row background color extend the full width, including outside of the safe area

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

In a SwiftUI `List`, how can I make a list row background (set via `.listRowBackground()`) extend the full width of the view, even under the safe area? E.g. when running in landscape on a wide iPhone (iPhone 12 Pro Max, for example). Currently, the cell appears white on the far left of the cell until the start of the safe area.

Example code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Test")
                .listRowBackground(Color(.systemGray3))
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

This produces a UI as shown below. I would like the grey background of the cell to extend the full width of the device.

I've tried adding `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` to the `Text` but it makes no difference.

[image: List running on iPhone 12 Pro Max in landscape, with the far left of the cell appearing white, unlike the rest of the cell which is grey]

Comment: I love you my man ... your code saved my day :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is to put `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.leading, .trailing])` on the background `Color` itself, rather than the list item.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Test").listRowBackground(
                Color(.systemGray3).edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.leading, .trailing])
            )
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: A shorter version is `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)`.

Comment: This doesn't work. Change the color and you will it's actually applying a default row background color and not stretching the Text space.

Comment: That was what the question was about: extending the background colour into the safe area, not the Text.